# PHP verify url ends in two parts of path, one fixed and one variable

Tags: php, pattern-matching, preg-match

I have urls on my site like:

```
http://example.com/item/one/
http://example.com/item/two/
http://example.com/item/one/something
http://example.com/item/two/someotherthing
http://example.com/other/one/
http://example.com/other/two/
```

And I want to check the url and redirect if it matches `/item/one/` or `/item/two/` but NOT if it matches just `/one/` or `/two/`, and NOT matching any string that goes deeper like `something`.

Ideally, I would want to match anything that contains both `/item/` and one final path after that (ie `/item/three/`,`/item/four/` as well).

What would be the best way to accomplish the match? preg_match (not sure how to write it for this)? explode?

**UPDATE**
Tried the following:

```
$thisurl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (preg_match("/^\/item\/(.*)\/$/", $thisurl)) {
    echo "it matches";
} else {
    echo "nope nope nope";
}
```

Which works in [this tester](http://www.phpliveregex.com/), but fails in my code (because it also matches true for things like:

```
http://example.com/item/one/something
http://example.com/item/two/someotherthing
```

which it should not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex does the job:

```
~/item/[^/]+/$~i
```

**Explanation:**

```
~           : regex delimiter
  /item/    : literally
  [^/]+     : 1 or more character that is NOT a slash
  /         : a slash
  $         : end of string
~i          : regex delimiter + case insensitive
```

**In use:**

```
$tests = array(
    'http://example.com/item/one/',
    'http://example.com/item/two/',
    'http://example.com/item/one/something',
    'http://example.com/item/two/someotherthing',
    'http://example.com/other/one/',
    'http://example.com/other/two/'
);
foreach($tests as $test) {
    echo "$test --> ";
    if (preg_match('~/item/[^/]+/$~i', $test)) {
        echo "valid\n";
    } else {
        echo "invalid\n";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
http://example.com/item/one/ --> valid
http://example.com/item/two/ --> valid
http://example.com/item/one/something --> invalid
http://example.com/item/two/someotherthing --> invalid
http://example.com/other/one/ --> invalid
http://example.com/other/two/ --> invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do it using the explode function.

```
 $url = [
        'http://example.com/item/one/',
        'http://example.com/item/two/',
        'http://example.com/item/one/something',
        'http://example.com/item/two/someotherthing',
        'http://example.com/other/one/',
        'http://example.com/other/two/'
    ];

    foreach($url as $row){
        $path = explode('/',str_replace('http://example.com/','',rtrim($row,'/')));

        if(count($path) != 2){
            continue;
        }

        if($path[0] != "item"){
            continue;
        }

        if(in_array($path[1],[
            'one',
            'two'
        ])){
            echo 'redirect...';
        }
    }
```

However a better answer would probably involve using some form of regex.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working with this:

```
if (preg_match("/^\/item\/[-a-z]+\/$/", $thisurl)) { //matches any lowercase word that may or may not contain a dash
echo "it matches";
} else {
echo "nope nope nope";
}
```

DESPITE [this page](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) telling me that `preg_match("/^\/item\/(.*)\/$/", $thisurl)` would work, it did not.